# Airflow not scheduling Correctly Python

Tags: python, airflow

**Code:**

**Python version 2.7.x and airflow version 1.5.1**

my dag script is this

```
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators import BashOperator
from datetime import datetime, timedelta


default_args = {
'owner': 'xyz',
'depends_on_past': False,
'start_date': datetime(2015,10,13),
'email': ['xyz@email.in'],
'schedule_interval':timedelta(minutes=5),
'email_on_failure': True,
'email_on_retry': True,
'retries': 1,
'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=5),
}
dag = DAG('testing', default_args=default_args)
run_this_first = BashOperator(task_id='Start1',bash_command='date', dag=dag)
for i in range(5):
    t = BashOperator(task_id="Orders1"+str(i), bash_command='sleep 5',dag=dag)
    t.set_upstream(run_this_first)
```

From that you could see that I am creating a DAG with 6 tasks the first task(Start1) starts first after which all the other five tasks starts

Currently I have given 5 minutes time delay between DAG's starting

It has ran perfectly for all the six tasks the first type but after five minutes the DAG is not re-initiated

It has been more then 1 hour still the DAG is not re-initiated I really don't know were I am wrong .

It would be really nice if some one could point me out what is wrong .I tried clearing using `airflow testing clear` then to the same thing happen.It ran first instance then just stood there.

The only thing the command line shows is `Getting all instance for DAG testing`

When I change the position of the schedule_interval it just runs with out any schedule interval parallel.That is with in 5 minutes 300 or more task instance has been completed. There is no 5 minute schedule interval

**Code 2:**

```
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators import BashOperator
from datetime import datetime, timedelta


default_args = {
'owner': 'xyz',
'depends_on_past': False,
'start_date': datetime(2015,10,13),
'email': ['xyz@email.in'],
'email_on_failure': True,
'email_on_retry': True,
'retries': 1,
'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=5),
}
dag = DAG('testing',schedule_interval=timedelta(minutes=5),default_args=default_args)#Schedule here
run_this_first = BashOperator(task_id='Start1',bash_command='date', dag=dag)
for i in range(5):
    t = BashOperator(task_id="Orders1"+str(i), bash_command='sleep 5',dag=dag)
    t.set_upstream(run_this_first)
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For Code 2, I guess the reason why it runs every minute is:

1. The start time is 2015-10-13 00:00
2. The schedule interval is 5 minutes
3. Every heartbeat of scheduler(5 seconds by default), your DAG will be checked

   - First check: start date(no last execution date found) + scheduler
     interval < current time? If yes the DAG will be executed and last
     execution time will be recorded. (eg. 2015-10-13 00:00 + 5min < current?)
   - Second check on next heartbeat:  last execution time + scheduler
     interval < current time? If so the DAG will be executed again.
   - ....

The solution is set the DAG start_date as `datetime.now() - schedule_interval`.

And also if you want to debug:

1. Setting the LOGGINGLEVEL to `debug` in settings.py
2. Modify class method `is_queueable()` of `airflow.models.TaskInstance` to

:

```
def is_queueable(self, flag_upstream_failed=False):
    logging.debug('Checking whether task instance is queueable or not!')
    if self.execution_date > datetime.now() - self.task.schedule_interval:
        logging.debug('Too early to execute: execution_date {0} + task.schedule_interval {1} > datetime.now() {2}'.format(self.execution_date, self.task.schedule_interval, datetime.now()))
        return False
        ...
```

Comment: so you are saying that it will run for every five seconds until the execution date meats the current date time after which it will follow the scheduled time interval

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean.

Comment: thanks a lot mate but I have two doubts .how can I schedule a task a starting from this second  with a schedule interval of one hour.Can I schedule a job for the future

Answer (score 4):

Because the start time(2015-10-13 00:00) less than now time, it triggers the airflow [backfill](http://airflow.readthedocs.org/en/latest/cli.html). It will run from 2015-10-13 00:00 when every seconds the airflow scheduler detected(its the Start Date), but Execution Date is between 5 min(task interval time).

See the log name:

```
$tree airflow/logs/testing/
testing/
|-- Orders10
|   |-- 2015-10-13T00:00:00
|   |-- 2015-10-13T00:05:00
|   -- 2015-10-13T00:10:00
|-- Orders11
|   |-- 2015-10-13T00:00:00
|   |-- 2015-10-13T00:05:00
|   -- 2015-10-13T00:10:00
|-- Orders12
|   |-- 2015-10-13T00:00:00
|   |-- 2015-10-13T00:05:00
|   -- 2015-10-13T00:10:00
|-- Orders13
|   |-- 2015-10-13T00:00:00
|   |-- 2015-10-13T00:05:00
|   -- 2015-10-13T00:10:00
|-- Orders14
|   |-- 2015-10-13T00:00:00
|   |-- 2015-10-13T00:05:00
|   -- 2015-10-13T00:10:00
-- Start1
    |-- 2015-10-13T00:00:00
    |-- 2015-10-13T00:05:00
    |-- 2015-10-13T00:10:00
    -- 2015-10-13T00:15:00
```

See the create time of logs:

```
$ll airflow/logs/testing/Start1
-rw-rw-r-- 1 admin admin 4192 Nov  9 14:50 2015-10-13T00:00:00
-rw-rw-r-- 1 admin admin 4192 Nov  9 14:50 2015-10-13T00:05:00
-rw-rw-r-- 1 admin admin 4192 Nov  9 14:51 2015-10-13T00:10:00
-rw-rw-r-- 1 admin admin 4192 Nov  9 14:52 2015-10-13T00:15:00
```

Also, you can see the Task Instances on web UI:

[image: air flow Task Instances]