# Apache Airflow scheduler does not trigger DAG at schedule time

Tags: python, cron, airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs

When I schedule DAGs to run at a specific time everyday, the DAG execution does not take place at all. 
However, when I restart Airflow webserver and scheduler, the DAGs execute once on the scheduled time for that particular day and do not execute from the next day onwards.
I am using Airflow version v1.7.1.3 with python 2.7.6.
Here goes the DAG code:

```
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.bash_operator import BashOperator
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

import time
n=time.strftime("%Y,%m,%d")
v=datetime.strptime(n,"%Y,%m,%d")
default_args = {
    'owner': 'airflow',
    'depends_on_past': True,
    'start_date': v,
    'email': ['airflow@airflow.com'],
    'email_on_failure': False,
    'email_on_retry': False,
    'retries': 1,
    'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=10),

}

dag = DAG('dag_user_answer_attempts', default_args=default_args, schedule_interval='03 02 * * *')

# t1, t2 and t3 are examples of tasks created by instantiating operators
t1 = BashOperator(
    task_id='user_answer_attempts',
    bash_command='python /home/ubuntu/bigcrons/appengine-flask-skeleton-master/useranswerattemptsgen.py',
    dag=dag)
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 38):

Your issue is the `start_date` being set for the current time. Airflow runs jobs at the *end* of an interval, not the beginning. This means that the first run of your job is going to be after the first interval.

Example:

You make a dag and put it live in Airflow at midnight. Today (20XX-01-01 00:00:00) is also the start_date, but it is hard-coded (`"start_date":datetime(20XX,1,1)`). The schedule interval is daily, like yours (`3 2 * * *`).

The first time this dag will be queued for execution is 20XX-01-02 02:03:00, because that is when the interval period *ends*. If you look at your dag being run at that time, it should have a started datetime of roughly one day after the schedule_date.

You can solve this by having your `start_date` hard-coded to a date *or* by making sure that the dynamic date is further in the past than the interval between executions (In your case, 2 days would be plenty). Airflow recommends you use static start_dates in case you need to re-run jobs or backfill (or end a dag).

For more information on backfilling (the opposite side of this common stackoverflow question), check the docs or this question:
[Airflow not scheduling Correctly Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33126159/airflow-not-scheduling-correctly-python)

Comment: could you explain me what this means?  `Airflow runs jobs at the end of an interval, not the beginning. This means that the first run of your job is going to be after the first interval.`

Comment: @nagasatish 

Let's say your exact start_date is today at 9 AM and your interval is every one hour.

`
start_date = days_ago(0)  # Today (Let's pretend that start_date is exactly 9 AM today).
schedule_interval = "0 * * * *"  # Every hour.
 `

Your first run will be triggered at 10 AM, means that your data in 9 AM will be processed in 10 AM.
**First_run = start_date + interval**

Answer (score 3):

Check the following:

1. start_date is a fix time in the past(don't use datetime.now())
2. if you don't want to run the historical data, use catchup=false
3. to set a specific time for DAG to run (e.g hourly, monthly, daily, at a specific time), try using
   https://crontab.guru/#40_21_*_*_* to write what you need.
4. If you think you have 1, 2, 3 steps all correct but the DAG is not running. Or the DAG can run every xx minutes, but failed to trigger even once in a daily interval, try create a new python file, copy your DAG code there, rename it so that the file is unique and then test again. It could be the case that airflow scheduler got confused by the inconsistency between previous DAG Runs' metadata and the current schedule.

Hope this helped!

Comment: Why would #4 be necessary? What is going on under the hood that would cause the scheduler to parse two different python files with the exact same dag definition code differently?

Answer (score 2):

From the schedule your DAG should run everyday at 02:03 AM. My suspicion is the start_date might be impacting it. Can you hardcode that to something like 'start_date': datetime.datetime(2016, 11, 01) and try.

Answer (score -3):

Great answer [apathyman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7864773/apathyman).
It helped me a lot to understand. I was using days_ago(0) and once I changed it to days_ago(1), scheduler started triggering.

Comment: this should be a comment