# Airflow scheduler fails to pickup scheduled DAG's but runs when triggered manually

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

I have Airflow 1.10.2 installation with python 3.5.6.

Metadata is lying into Mysql database with LocalExecutor for execution.

I have created sample helloworld.py dag with below schedule.

```
default_args = {
        'owner': 'Ashish',
        'depends_on_past': False,
        'start_date': datetime(2019, 2, 15),
        'email_on_failure': False,
        'email_on_retry': False,
        'retries': 1,
        'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=1),
    }

dag = DAG('Helloworld',schedule_interval='56 6 * * *', default_args=default_args)
```

But scheduler didn't pickup this dag as per scheduled time whereas when i run it manually from UI it runs perfectly fine.

Concern here is why does scheduler fails to pickup dag run as per the scheduled time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are confused on `start_date:`. Your current schedule is set to run at 6:56 AM UTC on 2/15/2019. With this schedule, the DAG will run tomorrow with no problem. This is because Airflow runs jobs at the **end** of an interval, not the beginning.

`start_date:` is not when you want the DAG to be triggered, but when you want the scheduling interval to start. If you wanted your job to run today, start date should be: `'start_date': datetime(2019, 2, 14)`. Then your current daily scheduling interval would have ended at 6:56 AM today as intended and your DAG would have ran.

Taken from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40714087/apache-airflow-scheduler-does-not-trigger-dag-at-schedule-time?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Comment: Yes, there was some confusion with start_date, so did some experiments with other example.   Even we can use 'start_date': airflow.utils.dates.days_ago(1)  to run my dag as on Today.     Thanks @Zack.