# Airflow job not runinng as scheduled

Tags: airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs

I have a job that i had set to run a 9:00 UTC on Wednesday. It didn't run as planned by the end of the delay interval, which I thought was curious because I believe I have everything defined properly.

```
default_args = {
    'start_date': airflow.utils.dates.days_ago(0),
    'retries': 1,
    'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=5)
}

dag = DAG(
    'noncomp_trial',
    default_args=default_args,
    description='test of dag',
    schedule_interval='0 9 * * 3',
    dagrun_timeout=timedelta(minutes=20))
```

If anyone has any advice here that would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Apache Airflow scheduler does not trigger DAG at schedule time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40714087/apache-airflow-scheduler-does-not-trigger-dag-at-schedule-time)

Answer (score 0):

The Airflow Scheduler runs tasks once the `start_date` + one `schedule_interval` value has passed.  In your example, the DAG won't run until 9:00AM on Wednesday the following week occurs.

See more information about the relationship between the `start_date` and `schedule_interval` [here](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/concepts/scheduler.html).

You could try setting your `start_date` to a static date in the past by a week or two to see if that works? And to make sure the Scheduler doesn't try to execute every `start_date` + `schedule_interval` occurrence between that new `start_date` and now, you can set `catchup=False` on the DAG. For example:

```py
from datetime import datetime

dag = DAG(
    'noncomp_trial',
    default_args= {
        'start_date': datetime(2021, 7, 1),
        'retries': 1,
        'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=5)
    },
    description='test of dag',
    schedule_interval='0 9 * * 3',
    dagrun_timeout=timedelta(minutes=20),
    catchup=False,
)
```

Comment: is that just how the scheduler works when the job gets initialized? seems strange that i would need to schedule something a week in advance for it to run when i want it to

Comment: That is how the scheduler will determine what needs to be executed all the time but getting DAGs to run initially you'll need to think of what the `start_date` needs to be to handle the `start_date` + `schedule_interval` methodology.  It's not that you necessarily need to schedule it a week in advance, just think about what the `start_date` value should be.  There is an Airflow improvement proposed to make the scheduling mechanism more robust and intuitive: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/AIRFLOW/AIP-39+Richer+scheduler_interval